# tikz command fails after .cls file change

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The following tex content is a part a tex file which is added to main file with command `input`. With a new .cls and some other unrelated changes, tex isn't compiling with error message of

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/every node/.style={align=
center}' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

The related tex is as follows.

```
\newcommand{\graphitemize}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={align=center}]  
  \node[minimum size=3.0cm,circle,fill=gray!40,text=white,outer sep=1cm,inner sep=.5cm,very thick](ce){#1};  
\foreach \gritem [count=\xi] in {#2}
{\global\let\maxgritem\xi}  
\foreach \gritem [count=\xi] in {#2}
{% 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\maxgritem*\xi}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
\node[circle,
     ultra thick,
     draw=white,
     fill opacity=.6,
     fill=\col,        
     minimum size=3cm] at (ce.\angle) {\gritem };}%


\end{tikzpicture}  
}%
\graphitemize{Alignment}{Organizational\\Strategy,Enterprise \\Architecture,Business \\ Process\\Management,Requirements\\ Engineering}
```

Minimal Working Example is shared in [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9kruQqpAmMgOTMyRXFXRUNCb2s&usp=sharing). main.tex is the working tex file, while main2.tex has compile error. Only the `\documentclass .cls` file is different.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can consider to use `smartdiagram` package for this drawing: if I remember correctly the diagram you're after is called `bubble diagram`.

Comment: The problem goes away if you put your definition in the preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said when command definition is in the preamble, the compile error goes away. If there is an explanation, why two `.cls` definition differs in this way, it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

As percusse hinted in the comments, the problem goes away if the definition is put in the preamble.